# How to make a click popup window using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a button that can pop up a window when the button is clicked~

But when the window pops up, click the green menu, the menu will not disappear, only click again or any blank space around the menu! The

menu will be closed again, but I I wrote a judgment why this function cannot be realized?
I hope to get your help, thank you.

```js
const el = document.querySelector('.click')
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');

el.onclick = function() {
  menu.classList.toggle("showmenu");
}

window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.classList.contains('menu') || !e.classList.contains('menu_item')) {
    menu.removeClass('showmenu');
  }
}
```

```css
.click {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 20px;
}

.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.showmenu {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="click">click</button>
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">item1</a></li>
  <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">item2</a></li>
  <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">item3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few problems:

- Your global `click` event listener is trying to get the `classList` property of the event, which doesn't exist. You should instead be getting the target of the event, which is retrieved through the `target` property.
- There is no `removeClass` method. Use [`classList.remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/remove) instead.
- Call [`Event.stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) in the `click` event listener binded to `.click`, so the global `click` event listener will not handle the event (otherwise it will close the menu immediately after it was opened).

```js
const el = document.querySelector('.click')
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');

el.onclick = function(e) {
  menu.classList.toggle("showmenu");
  e.stopPropagation();
}

window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!menu.contains(e.target)) {
    menu.classList.remove('showmenu');
  }
}
```

```css
.click {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 20px;
}

.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.showmenu {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="click">click</button>
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">item1</a></li>
  <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">item2</a></li>
  <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">item3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your attentive reply, but how to describe my problem!
I hope that the menu will disappear only if you click click again and outside the menu, but now your code seems to click the menu, that is, the green block will also make the menu disappear?

Comment: @AWEI I've updated my answer. It should work now. Sorry for the delay :)

Comment: The links in the menu do not work...

Comment: @zer00ne They do. The `href` attribute is simply set to `#`.

Comment: Ah! derp!!!! 

Comment: Haha~ I only put # in the right menu because it's just for stating the problem

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery method `.removeClass()` was used on a plain JavaScript object (ie `menu`). In the example `.classList.remove()` was used instead. If you want to use `.removeClass()` instead, you must convert `menu` into a jQuery object `const menu = $('.menu')` then `menu.removeClass('showmenu')` will work.

Also, I changed the CSS a little to stop the button from jumping and to tame those links -- they bled from the menu's *percieved* borders. The CSS of course is not a requirement of solution.

**Solution**

Make all of the event handlers into a single event handler and delegate behavior with [control flow statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Control_flow), [`Event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) property, and [`.matches()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) method. The following uses the programming paradigm called [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation).

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.click')

document.body.onclick = popUp;

function popUp(e) {
  const clicked = e.target;
  const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');

  if (clicked.matches('.click')) {
    menu.classList.toggle("showmenu");
  } else if (!clicked.matches('.click') && !clicked.matches('.menu')) {
    menu.classList.remove('showmenu');
  } else return false;
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.click {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 20px;
}

.menu {
  display: none;
  background-color: green;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.showmenu {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="click">click</button>
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu_item"><a href="/#">item1</a></li>
  <li class="menu_item"><a href="/#">item2</a></li>
  <li class="menu_item"><a href="/#">item3</a></li>
</ul>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```